# maintain cookie for browser even when user session is expired in django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have a requirement where I want to set a cookie in the browser. This cookie is not 100% related to the user session, am trying to capture the desktop preferred setting.

I want to store this setting into a cookie that will not expire when the user logs out. Am using django in my implementation,

Please advise if there is something we can do?

Answer (score 1):

setcookie("user", $username, time()+604800); /* Expires in a week */

"604800" represents the time the coockie will "live"
 for example

One Minute: 60
Ten Minutes: 600
Half-an-Hour: 1800
One Hour: 3600
One Day: 86400
One Week: 604800
Two Weeks: 1209600
One Month (30 days): 2592000
One Year (365 days): 31536000

Comment: but when the user logs out. The cookie will be destroyed and I would like to maintain the cookie as long as possible.

Comment: No customly created cookies are not related to sessions are will not destroyed once a user is logged out.

Comment: Yes normally cookie will be there unless the response reset it(this is what log out do) or it was expired by time.

Comment: sessions and cookies are not related once you set the cookie on it's on , and it's never deleted it just expires and stays in the cookie folder of the user until he cleans up his browser.

Comment: also if you notice. in case you want to log out a user , it's kind of a game with the cookie... setting it the expire date of it to the past.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the funny hack: [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/).

> evercookie is a javascript API available that produces
>   extremely persistent cookies in a browser. Its goal
>   is to identify a client even after they've removed standard
>   cookies, Flash cookies (Local Shared Objects or LSOs), and
>   others.
>    
>   evercookie accomplishes this by storing the cookie data in
>   several types of storage mechanisms that are available on
>   the local browser. Additionally, if evercookie has found the
>   user has removed any of the types of cookies in question, it
>   recreates them using each mechanism available.